# Does a linear transformation have to be full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

My intuition tells me the answer is "no".

However, the textbook I use says that for a linear transformation $A: \mathcal{V} \rightarrow \mathcal{W}$, we usually pick natural basis and therefore $\mathcal{L}V=WA$ becomes $\mathcal{L}=A$. It seems that $A$ is the basis after the linear transformation and hence should be full rank, which is contrary to my intuition.

I want to use the fact about the rank 
$$rank(A) + rank(B) - n \leq rank(AB) \leq \min\{rank(A),rank(B)\}$$
to prove or disprove my intuition, but I failed.

Could anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The transform $A: \mathcal{V} \rightarrow \mathcal{W}:v\to0$ is undisputably linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, a linear map does not have to have full rank. The zero map between any two vector spaces is always linear.

A projection map such as $p:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $p(x,y):=(x,0)$ is also linear but does not have full rank.